# Apache 2.4 switches MPM after upgrade

Tags: apache-2.4

We're running Apache2.4 with mpm_event ("sudo a2enmod mpm_event") and an PHP-FPM backend behind that. Everything's great but when I'm occasionally upgrading my packages ("apt-get upgrade") Apache is switching back to mpm_prefork, making my configuration obsolete and taking done my site. Does anyone know how to tell it NOT to switch the MPM after an upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

The switch happens because of the post-upgrade script that runs after upgrading the libapache2-mod-php5 package. It isn't safe to use the php5 Apache2 module without the prefork MPM, so the script intervenes to try and fix the situation.

Unfortunately, the problem is that the script in question doesn't actually check if the php5 Apache2 module is really enabled. A [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=799630) has been filed about this issue.

In the mean time, to prevent the MPM from being switched again, you can simply uninstall the libapache2-mod-php5 package.